# int == different int is true?

Tags: javascript, int, compare

I am trying to compare between two ints (one inside an array inside of an object)
and for some reason the result is always true.

```
var answerCheck = function(){
    alert(vidobject.correctanswer[currentquestion]);
    if(answer === vidobject.correctanswer[currentquestion]);
    {
        alert(answer);
        alert("correct answer!");
    }
```

When I alert both of those ints before they compare, the result of both is 
either 1 or 2 or 3 (Both can have different values)

Any solutions to why this might occur?

Comment: you have a `;` at the end of your `if` condition, which means that the `;` is the only expression inside your if clause while the rest `{ alert(answer);...}` will always be executed, no matter how your `if` gets evaluated

Comment: wow this is stupid,thanks for noticing! i just searched online and saw that there are some restrictions on comparing,thanks!